# JPA cascade none does not work

Tags: hibernate, jpa, hibernate-mapping, jpa-2.1, hibernate-cascade

Scenario:

```
`
@Entity
@Table(name = "a")
@AttributeOverride(name = "id", column = @Column(name = "a_id"))
public class A {
   private ...
   private List<> ....
}`

`
@Entity
@Table(name = "b")
@AttributeOverride(name = "id", column = @Column(name = "b_id"))
public class B {
  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn(name = "a_id", referencedColumnName = "a_id")
  private A a;

  @Column(name = "last_opened_date")
  private DateTime lastOpenedDate;

  @ManyToOne(fetch = javax.persistence.FetchType.LAZY)
  @JoinColumn(name = "opened_by_id", referencedColumnName = "user_id")
  private User openedBy;
}`
```

- Whenever A is accessed in a view, A's state get changed.
- A can be accessed by many users.
- As soon as A is accessed, an instance of B is created( if not exists) or updated for each user who opens A.
- B always refer the state changed instance of A.
- As i have not mentioned cascade type in ManyToOne mapping in Class B (for class A), i assume default will be cascade none.

But whenever i opened A in a view, when B persists, state changed A also get persists. I don't want A to be persisted when i persist B.
How do i achieve that?

java 1.8, hibernate 4.3.7, wildfly 8.2

**Generic save method**:

```
public T save(T entity) throws PersistenceException {
    this.getEntityManager().joinTransaction();
    if (entity.getId() == null) {
        this.getEntityManager().persist(entity);
    } else {
        entity = this.getEntityManager().merge(entity);
    }
    return entity;
}
```

**Persistence xml**:

`<persistence version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="bla_bla" transaction-type="JTA">
        <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
        <jta-data-source>jdbc/bla</jta-data-source>
        <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>
        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.enable_lazy_load_no_trans" value="true"/>
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="false"/>
            <property name="hibernate.event.merge.entity_copy_observer" value="log"/>
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServer2008Dialect"/>
            <property name="hibernate.transaction.jta.platform" value="org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.JBossAppServerJtaPlatform"/>
            <!-- enabling L2 cache -->
            <property name="hibernate.cache.region.factory_class" value="org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.EhCacheRegionFactory"/>
            <property name="hibernate.generate_statistics" value ="false" /> 
            <property name="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache" value="true"/>
            <property name="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache" value="false"/>
            <property name="jadira.usertype.databaseZone" value="UTC"/>
            <property name="jadira.usertype.javaZone" value="UTC"/>
            <property name="jadira.usertype.autoRegisterUserTypes" value="true"/>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>`

Comment: so you present some entities but omit the most important part ... the persistence code, so some discussion about cascading is impossible. I've no idea what "opened" means

Comment: @NeilStockton thanx for the comment. I 've added persistence method. opened means, access this opbject, view the object contents in a UI.